# Need Architecture options for pulling data from Salesforce, to retrieve datasets

Tags: soql, workbench, architecture

My perspective is traditional RDBMS (Oracle), and retrieving data with a reporting tool like Business Objects or straight SQL Nothing too fancy, just dump to Excel. But JOINing a lotta tables.

We're migrating to SF but our analytics team still needs to pull all manner of data. Right now using SOQL using Workbench - this is painful imo.

Einstein doesn't seem like the right tool for us. It's set up for fancy dashboards and such, but that's not what we need to do.

SOQL is extremely limited imo. For example, I have two healthy queries that each "join" to several other tables. But I want to JOIN my two healthy tables, in the same manner one could JOIN to VIEWS fom Oracle. But I don't think SOQL allows that.

Plus, I don't think standard Salesforce reporting is going to work, although I haven't tried it out. But it just not seem like the way to do all of our reporting (data pulls).

For example, SOQL doesn't have logical LEFT JOINs, as I understand it. Say I have student(contacts), applications, and sports recruiting. In Oracle, I would start with STUDENTS, then LEFT JOIN to both applications and sports recruiting.

But in SOQL, it looks to me like you START with the "leaf" (sports recruiting), then work you way to the branch (applications) and THEN to the "root" (STUDENTS).

- so you wouldn't be able to count the number students with no applications nor the number of students with no sports recruiting.

So is my only architecture option is to suck the data out of SF into a traditional RDBMS and then JOIN everything (normally)?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Joins work in both directions from Salesforce. You just need a relationship between the tables (Lookup or Master-Detail). They used to have really good documentation about how left- and right- joins work, both -inner and -outer. But they pulled it and never replaced.

Comment: In our company we use a third party App Exchange product to regularly pull all data into a SQL db that we then use for more complex reporting and data analytics. The other option is to look into Heroku as I know they have a relatively simple way to get your data into a postgres db which may be of use.

Comment: Adrian - thanks. I will need to research more.
bpilling - thank you as well. Both options though mean that you can't report out of Salesforce directly, you have to dump it to ANOTHER database. I thought SF was fancy and such???

Comment: @WmPeck1958 Take a look at [Einstein Analytics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/wave_analytics_basics) (now renamed to Tableau CRM), it [does](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314263&type=1&mode=1) what you're looking for.

Comment: identigral - thank you. It's definitely on our radar.